# Error in starting NetBeans IDE.

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I am using net beans 6.0.1. There is an error when starting it. Error is;

```
  A java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception has occurred.
  Please report this at http://www.netbeans.org/community/issues.html,
  including a copy of your messages.log file as an attachment.
  The messages.log file is located in your C:\Documents and     
  Settings\Hasitha\.netbeans\6.0\var\log folder.
```

Here is a print screen of error.

[image]]

And size of folder ;

```
     C:\Documents and Settings\Hasitha\.netbeans\6.0\var\log
```

is increasing rapidly when i'm using netbeans.

How can i fix this??

Comment: And what does the log file say?

Comment: If this is your fault (you're a plugin developer), post the code that caused it. If it isn't your fault, this question is off-topic here. Try [su]

Comment: @WernerVesterås uigesture file is increasing size. Dont nkowwhatsthat file means.

Comment: @janDvorak Faultis with the IDE i think

Comment: Maybe the same as this: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=161691

Comment: @Hasi007 then it's off-topic on Stack Overflow. This site is for programming-related questions ("how do I implement this" or "why doesn't this work")

Comment: @WernerVesterås seems like a similar case

Comment: Upgrade NetBeans to > 6.7

Answer (score 0):

Make a clean install of Netbeans and re-install/update your JDK, as its a known Netbeans bug in pre-uptodate version. it is said to be fixed now.